# How can I make this Javascript score counter work?

Tags: javascript, counter

I'm trying to make a very simple dice rolling game so I can get the basics of Javascript.

It's two dice being rolled - one red, one blue - and a counter keeping score for each to see how many rounds each dice has won.

The dice roll fine but I'm having no luck at all with the counters. If the red one is higher then I want it's counter to increase by 1. Likewise for the blue. At the moment however, nothing happens.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="reds">
  <div id="die1">0</div>
  <div id="redCounter"></div>
</div>
<div id="blues">
  <div id="die2">0</div>
  <div id="blueCounter"></div>
</div>
```

And the relevent bit of Javascript:

```
var redCounter = document.getElementById("redCounter");
var blueCounter = document.getElementById("blueCounter");
var redScore = 0;
var blueScore = 0;

if(d1 < d2) {
  status.innerHTML += " <br>Blue Wins!";
  var blueCounter=+1;
  blueCounter.innterHTML= "Blue has " + blueScore + " points!";
}
else if(d1 > d2) {
  status.innerHTML += " <br>Red Wins!";
  var blueCounter=+1;
  document.getElementByID("redCounter").innterHTML=redCounter;
}
```

Can anyone give me any clue as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Keep variable global, initialize them as `0`, or else value will be over-written everytime..

Comment: What is d1 and d2? The `var` is an issue. Use a tool like http://jshint.com/

Comment: remove both `var` keyword from  the condition.

Comment: "_having no luck at all_" is not a problem description. What is the result you get, and what do you expect instead?

Comment: How are you even calling this code? If this is all in the same function then you reset the scores to zero every time you call it. Thats before you even get to your `if`

Comment: @Teemu - Sorry, not really used to the etiquette here yet. 

Two dice are rolled when a button is clicked - a red one and a blue one. If the red one is higher then I want it's counter to increase by 1. Likewise for the blue.

At the moment however, nothing happens.

Comment: @epascarello - d1 and d2 are the dice results (d1 is red, d2 is blue). Thanks, I'll remove the var.

Comment: @Timothyp Well, it's more about communication in general, than the "etiquette", which should not be disregarded either ... If you ask something, it would be nice to know, what exactly you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var blueCounter=+1 for example makes a new variable inside your if block and sets it to 1. And first you use blueCounter as dom element. If you want to add to your previously added blueCounter do it like this

```
   blueScore++;
   blueCounter.innerHTML = "Blue has " + blueScore + " Points";
```

Short: You are mixing up your DomElement blueCounter with your score variable blueScore

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - I've replaced my code with yours and now I get it showing "Blue has 1 points" when blue wins the first time, but subsequent wins do not increase this total - it stays at "1 point".

Comment: ah ok. you have to make your redScore and blueScore variables global and not in your RollDice function. Otherwise they will be reinitialized everytime you call the function.

Comment: I was wondering if that was the case, a global variable is one that is before the function that calls them, is that correct? I've tried putting the rollDice function just above the d1 and d2 variables and that makes the counters work correctly, but now I'm not getting the "Red / Blue wins!" messages in the "status" div.

Comment: try to keep your dom element variables like status and the counters in the function. As global javascript is rendered parallel with html it could be that javascript tries to call document.getElementById(...) before the element is rendered in html.
there is also an event that fires when the dom has loaded. These functions you would use normally when u initialize dom variables and other events.
`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work
});`  would be plain javascript and 
`$(document).ready(function()  {
//do work
})` would be the jquery equivalent